# Postfix still complains that "certificate verification failed" even when "smtp_tls_security_level = fingerprint"

Tags: postfix, smtp, ssl-certificate, starttls, fingerprint

I'm attempting to use Postfix (version 2.6.6 on RHEL6) to connect to and send mail via a mail relay on our internal network. I want to connect with STARTTLS on port 25 (port 465 is not available on this server). The mail relay uses a self-signed SSL/TLS certificate so I needed to skip certificate verification using a  certificate authority. I discovered the [`smtp_tls_security_level = fingerprint`](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_fprint) which does not check the trust chain, expiration date, etc. Instead it verifies using the certificate fingerprint.

I figured this was the perfect solution, but when I attempt to send an email, I still get errors in `/var/log/maillog` that say `postfix/smtp[15182]: certificate verification failed for xxxxxxxxxxxx[zz.zz.zz.zz]:25: untrusted issuer`.

**I thought the whole point of the `fingerprint` security level was to skip certificate verification. Am I misunderstanding the point of this option? Is there something else I need to configure?**

Here are the relevant lines from `main.cf`:

```
relayhost = [xxx.xxx.xxx]
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl-passwords
smtp_sasl_security_options=
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = fingerprint
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = sha1
# fingerprint changed for ServerFault. just an example.
smtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match = c1:d3:54:12:00:r0:ef:fa:42:48:10:ff:ac:1e:75:13:dd:ad:af:3e
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

Edit: added bold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question here. I did not manage to get `fingerprint` verification working, but I did discover how to get TLS without certificate verification. From the [manual](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_encrypt):

> Mandatory TLS encryption can be configured by setting "smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt". Even though TLS encryption is always used, mail delivery continues even if the server certificate is untrusted or bears the wrong name.

I had tried this at one point but must not have had all the right options enabled. But using the settings above, I simply changed `smtp_tls_security_level` to `encrypt` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since Postfix has enable chroot (by default in Debian) "/etc/postfix/master.cf":

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
```

and the default value for the variable **[smtp_tls_CAfile](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_CAfile)** is empty, the solution pass for setting it with the location of the certificates file inside de chroot:

In "/etc/postfix/main.cf":

```
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score -1):

assumming you have your certificate files ready
edit file /etc/postfix/main.cf :

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/YOURFILE.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/YOURFILE.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/YOURFILE.crt
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
```

(change file name and path accordingly)

I confirm Let's encrypt is okay, no need a real 3rd party certificate.